# Docker build exited with code 1 : What am I doing wrong?

Tags: docker

I'm a beginner at running Docker and I build a virtual machine to run PHP5.6, MySql 5.5 on Debian:Jessie for a small project of mine.

The container builds just fine with all dependencies but it does not want to start properly. I'm either getting "exited with code 1" error or "exited with code 0" and the container closing itself.

Here are my files, I'm probably missing something but I've been spending days on this and I could not find it.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
#Download base image Debien 8 (Jessie)
FROM debian:jessie

ADD . /var/www/

RUN apt-get update

# Adding PHP 7.1 repository
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list

RUN apt-get update

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.1
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server mysql-client
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git git-core
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y curl zip unzip gzip

# Composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '93b54496392c062774670ac18b134c3b3a95e5a5e5c8f1a9f115f203b75bf9a129d5daa8ba6a13e2cc8a1da0806388$
RUN php composer-setup.php
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

# Configure Apache
RUN rm -rf /var/www/* \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
ADD vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
#RUN service apache2 restart
RUN rm -f /run/apache2/apache2.pid
CMD apachectl -DFOREGROUND -e info

# Add main start script for when image launches
ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod 775 /run.sh

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["sh", "./run.sh"]
```

Here is the run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod -R 775 /var/www
chown -R 1000:www-data /var/www
source /etc/apache2/envvars
exec apache2 -D FOREGROUND
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
```

And here is the kind of output I get:

```
lain@navidebi:~/Sites/ceizyl.fr$ docker-compose --verbose up
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/lain/.docker/config.json', '/home/lain/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Found file at path: /home/lain/.docker/config.json
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'auths' section
docker.auth.parse_auth: Found entry (registry='https://index.docker.io/v1/', username='jinxy')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/version HTTP/1.1" 200 535
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe
docker-py version: 3.4.1
CPython version: 3.6.6
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localhost
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: Platform={'Name': ''}, Components=[{'Name': 'Engine', 'Version': '18.06.1-ce', 'Details': {'ApiVersion': '1.38', 'Arch': 'amd64', 'BuildTime': '2018-08-21T17:22:21.000000000+00:00', 'Experimental': 'false', 'GitCommit': 'e68fc7a', 'GoVersion': 'go1.10.3', 'KernelVersion': '4.9.0-8-amd64', 'MinAPIVersion': '1.12', 'Os': 'linux'}}], Version=18.06.1-ce, ApiVersion=1.38, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=e68fc7a, GoVersion=go1.10.3, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=4.9.0-8-amd64, BuildTime=2018-08-21T17:22:21.000000000+00:00
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('ceizylfr_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/networks/ceizylfr_default HTTP/1.1" 200 445
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network -> {'Attachable': False,
 'ConfigFrom': {'Network': ''},
 'ConfigOnly': False,
 'Containers': {},
 'Created': '2018-10-09T22:11:40.811373843+02:00',
 'Driver': 'bridge',
 'EnableIPv6': False,
 'IPAM': {'Config': [{'Gateway': '172.18.0.1', 'Subnet': '172.18.0.0/16'}],
          'Driver': 'default',
          'Options': None},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info <- ()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/info HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info -> {'Architecture': 'x86_64',
 'BridgeNfIp6tables': True,
 'BridgeNfIptables': True,
 'CPUSet': True,
 'CPUShares': True,
 'CgroupDriver': 'cgroupfs',
 'ClusterAdvertise': '',
 'ClusterStore': '',
 'ContainerdCommit': {'Expected': '468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e',
                      'ID': '468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e'},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('ceizylfr_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/networks/ceizylfr_default HTTP/1.1" 200 445
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network -> {'Attachable': False,
 'ConfigFrom': {'Network': ''},
 'ConfigOnly': False,
 'Containers': {},
 'Created': '2018-10-09T22:11:40.811373843+02:00',
 'Driver': 'bridge',
 'EnableIPv6': False,
 'IPAM': {'Config': [{'Gateway': '172.18.0.1', 'Subnet': '172.18.0.0/16'}],
          'Driver': 'default',
          'Options': None},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=ceizylfr', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/json?limit=-1&all=0&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dceizylfr%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=ceizylfr', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/json?limit=-1&all=0&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dceizylfr%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=ceizylfr', 'com.docker.compose.service=web', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dceizylfr%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dweb%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 1139
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': [],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['/run.sh'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
            'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'],
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('ceizylfr_web')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/images/ceizylfr_web/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {'Architecture': 'amd64',
 'Author': '',
 'Comment': '',
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['/run.sh'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=ceizylfr', 'com.docker.compose.service=web', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dceizylfr%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dweb%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 1139
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('ceizylfr_web')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/images/ceizylfr_web/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {'Architecture': 'amd64',
 'Author': '',
 'Comment': '',
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['/run.sh'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': [],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['/run.sh'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
            'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'],
...
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Service: web>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Service: web>
Starting ceizylfr_web_1 ... 
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Container: ceizylfr_web_1 (42b6dc)>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Container: ceizylfr_web_1 (42b6dc)>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach <- ('42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8', stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True)
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.22/containers/42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8/attach?logs=0&stdout=1&stderr=1&stream=1 HTTP/1.1" 101 0
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x7f651c028ac8>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start <- ('42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8')
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.22/containers/42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8/start HTTP/1.1" 204 0
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start -> None
Starting ceizylfr_web_1 ... done
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: <Service: web>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
Attaching to ceizylfr_web_1
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <- (filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=ceizylfr', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']}, decode=True)
web_1  | standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/events?filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dceizylfr%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x7f651c061ac8>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- ('42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.22/containers/42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8/wait HTTP/1.1" 200 30
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 1}
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/42b6dc90b0aed25c35d4f7fe42ebce5fc70a634e6bcf26141e7532eac46390e8/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
ceizylfr_web_1 exited with code 1
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': [],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['/run.sh'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
            'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'],
...
```

Please help me I'm getting desperate.

Comment: That’s...a lot of data, and it’s not immediately obvious what’s wrong.  Can you reduce this to a [mcve] and explain what incorrect behavior you’re seeing?

Comment: standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error" seems to indicate that you are running a go binary that is not compatible with the machine you are running on. Try recompiling the go code.

Comment: Also in your Dockerfile you have 2 CMD statements, only one is getting executed. So probably your image has something different from what you're expecting. CMD statements run only when the container is executed, not during build time.